# Calling git from R

Tags: git, r, system

I try to invoke git commands from the R console, but got stuck.
I use git bash version 1.7.11 in MINGW32, the path is C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i"..
OS is Windows 7.

```
script <- "C:\\Users\\Kay\\Dropbox\\R-Scripts\\test.R"
system(paste("git add", script), intern=TRUE)
system(paste('"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin\\sh.exe\"',
             'cd theBioBucket-Archives'), intern=TRUE)
system(paste('"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin\\sh.exe\"',
             'git add', script), intern=TRUE)
system(paste("git commit -a -m", "'", "autocommit", "'"), intern=TRUE)

[1] "/usr/bin/sh: cd: No such file or directory"
attr(,"status")
[1] 127
Warnmeldung:
Ausführung von Kommando '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" cd theBioBucket-Archives' ergab Status 127
```

I also tried:

```
system("C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\cmd.exe /c \"\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin\\sh.exe\" git status", intern=TRUE)
[1] "Der Befehl \"\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Git\\bin\\sh.exe git status\" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder"
[2] "konnte nicht gefunden werden."                                                                             
attr(,"status")
[1] 1
Warnmeldung:
Ausführung von Kommando 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe /c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" git status' ergab Status 1
```

with no luck, either..

edit 19.09.2012, my environment:

```
> Sys.getenv("PATH")
[1] "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\AMD APP\\bin\\x86_64;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\AMD APP\\bin\\x86;C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\Windows Live;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Microsoft Shared\\Windows Live;C:\\Windows\\system32;C:\\Windows;C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Live\\Shared;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ATI Technologies\\ATI.ACE\\Core-Static;C:\\Program Files\\MiKTex\\miktex\\bin\\"
> normalizePath(R.home("bin"))
[1] "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-2.15.1\\bin\\x64"
> shell("R --version")
Der Befehl "R" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.
Warnmeldungen:
1: Ausführung von Kommando 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c R --version' ergab Status 1 
2: In shell("R --version") :
  'R --version' Ausführung mit Fehlerkode 1 fehlgeschlagen
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think creating a sub-shell can work. Plus "`cd: No such file or directory`" means said shell hasn't a proper PATH set.

It would be better to set the right PATH (and other environment variables if needed, as done in the [`git-cmd.bat`](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/devel/git-cmd.bat)), following the example of [this R script](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Update-MS-Windows-PATH-variable-based-on-a-R-script-td3633623.html), and see if a direct call to `git` commands works then.

The OP mentions [yihui script](https://github.com/yihui/lyx/blob/master/add-R-path-win.R):

```
## put R's bin path to the system PATH variable under Windows
R.bin = normalizePath(R.home("bin"))
sys.path = Sys.getenv("PATH")
if ((shell("R --version") != 0) || !grepl(R.bin, sys.path, fixed = TRUE)) {
    system(paste("setx PATH \"", R.bin, ";", sys.path, "\"", sep = ""))
}
```

And confirms it working with the right `PATH` (see "[How To Use Environment Variables in Windows XP](http://best-windows.vlaurie.com/environment-variables.html)"):

> I used the script by yihui and my `PATH` now contains git ..first try reveals that calls to git are now possible!

Comment: you mean this script - https://github.com/yihui/lyx/blob/master/add-R-path-win.R ?

Comment: @Kay that seem to be another technique. The script I reference should at least change the PATH within the R script execution, which should be enough for your git commands to work (and you need to complete your PATH: it doesn't reference a git installation directory)

Comment: sry, I don't manage to adjust the approach from the cited posting to my problem - any chance to get a more specific advise?

Comment: @Kay not with my (limited) experience in `R` ;) Did you manage to modify your `PATH` at the beginning of your script? Can you display said `PATH`, and does it contain the `<git>\bin` directory?

Comment: I used the script by yihui and my PATH now contains git ..first try reveals that calls to git are now possible! - thanks a lot for the usefull hints!

Comment: btw, for the illiterate (like me;) this may help to understand PATH: http://best-windows.vlaurie.com/environment-variables.html

Comment: @Kay good link, I have added it to the answer for more visibility.